# How to properly implement `ISpanFormattable.TryFormat()`?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-7.0

I have a class that implements `IFormattable` and I want to also implement `ISpanFormattable` as defined in C# 7

```
public partial interface ISpanFormattable : System.IFormattable
{
    bool TryFormat(Span<char> destination, out int charsWritten, ReadOnlySpan<char> format, IFormatProvider? provider);
}
```

Here is the implementation that I came up with, but I am not sure if this follows the logic it is intended to have. I am unclear about when to return true/false and how to handle the arguments correctly.

```
public class Foo : ISpanFormattable
{
    // other definitions

    #region Formatting
    public override string ToString() => ToString("g");
    public string ToString(string? formatting) => ToString(formatting, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
    public string ToString(string? formatting, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
    {
        // code to return a formatted string
    }

    public bool TryFormat(Span<char> destination, out int charsWritten, ReadOnlySpan<char> format, IFormatProvider? provider)
    {
        string formatting = format.ToString();
        string result = this.ToString(formatting, provider);
        charsWritten = Math.Min(result.Length, destination.Length);
        result.CopyTo(destination[..charsWritten] );
        return charsWritten == result.Length;
    }
    #endregion

}
```

What I have done is convert the `ReadOnlySpan<char> format` into a `string` in order to call the existing `ToString()` function, and then use the result to copy into the destination. The function will return `false` if the resulting string is larger than the destination `Span<char>`.

It seems a bit long for a basic wrapper around `ToString()`, and might be a performance bottleneck when converting `Span<char>` to `string`.

Is there a simpler/better way to implement `TryFormat()` for my class?

Comment: There is no point in implementing `ISpanFormattable` if you're going to be allocating strings anyway. The whole point of it is to do the formatting *without* creating new strings. Doing so typically involves calling the `.TryFormat` methods of primitive types, which match this signature.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I see your point. I knew something was off.  I saw another implementation and it had `ToString()` depending on `TryFormat()` and not the other way around like my code.